# GoogleAuthIOException Mobile Backend Starter - Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

After [deploying the backend](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/deploy_backend) for Mobile Backend Starter and [running android sample](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/android/), I encountered `GoogleAuthIOExceptio`

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException
```

I already tried `Secured by Client IDs` authentication option and used `Web Client ID` in both backend and android client, but still have the exception.

Comment: I just set up the sample guestbook app and get the exact same problem. Cloud console says the backend is deployed, the authentication is set to Open (for development use only) and in the Consts.java file I changed to my own project id.

Comment: Before the exception I get a warning: "Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName." Do you JR Galia, get that as well?

Comment: yes, I also get the warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set 
`public static final boolean IS_AUTH_ENABLED = false;` in Consts.java

Comment: After changing that to true in the Consts.java file it worked perfectly! Thanks! For reference I also got an exception about not having set the version of Google Play Services correctly. However, doing what the exception suggested (changing the version to @integer/google_play_services_version in the manifest) fixes it. I wonder why they don't ship the example that way?